# mongodb/mongoose make aggregate $lookup as optional

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this query of mongodb

```
Job.aggregate([ 
       {$match: {created_by: req.params.userId }},
       {$lookup: {
       from: "users", 
       localField: "applicant._id", 
       foreignField: "_id", 
       as: "applicant" }},
       {$unwind: '$applicant'}
     ])
```

It won't work when applicant._id is null. That's not what I want, how to make $lookup as optional?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`$lookup` does a outer join, it won't filter if there is no match.

The problem is with the `$unwind`, it will filter when the array is null or empty, in order to not filter empty arrays you need to specify `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays : true` in `$unwind` pipeline

```
Job.aggregate([ 
       {$match: {created_by: req.params.userId }},
       {$lookup: {
           from: "users", 
           localField: "applicant._id", 
           foreignField: "_id", 
           as: "applicant" }
       },
       {$unwind: {
           path :'$applicant', 
           preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}
       }
     ])
```

Comment: btw, why must $applicant have $ prefix?